# Resize Google Sheets Column (to width of selected cell)

Tags: google-sheets

Dblclicking the right border of a columnheader   will  resize the column according to the largest width of all its cells.

Instead How to  resize  according to the largest width of a single specific selected cell?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way of **automatically** resizing cells based on their contents that doesn't involve script. However if you know the width of a particular cell (perhaps by temporarily copying it into an empty column, double clicking on the column header border as you already have done, then right clicking on the column header and selecting 'resize column' to view the numerical value of the column width) and wish to apply that more widely, then you can bulk-resize columns to that size by clicking on their headers whilst holding Ctrl, then right click on any of the selected headers, select 'resize columns' and enter the appropriate width in the box.